# Dell R710 - No Video - Hardware-only DRAC reset option?

Tags: reset

Ok.. so.

Worst possible scenario with new (to me) server.

For whatever reason this server **does not output video** on either the front or rear VGA port.

..also, I went to reset the default password (as is good standard practice) to the local HTTP DRAC site, and it **will not accept the new password**.

So the scenario is thus:

Is there a *hardware* method to **reset the DRAC to defaults**? Again, I *do not have local video* (the machine powers up just fine it seems, and I used to be able to log into the DRAC), so I am **unable to just fire off the normal reset commands** from the local terminal.

I have scoured the internet for suggestions to the video problem to no avail, and now that I lost access to even the local DRAC HTTP site.. I am in a pickle.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm. First thing I'd check is if removing the DRAC power would reset it. Or if there's a physical jumper on it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? In a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I sure wish there was a solution here. All was well until I made a change to esxi to allow passthrough for ethernet and turned off "web server" in iDRAC. No video, no network. Just a noisy paperweight.

I did it!! I stumbled upon racadm commands and a couple hours later saw something about ssh. I remembered I had made it a point to have ssh on. In spite of not having a gui, I CAN connect with putty! 
Hope this helps someone. Commands in (  ) because I'm on my cell phone.

(racadm racreset) for a soft reset (no saved settings will be changed) or
(racadm racresetcfg) for a hard reset (IP/Account settings will be set back to factory default)